# My friend installed Ubuntu and I can't uninstall it or get into the BIOS anymore

Tags: boot, system-installation

My friend and I built a PC together out of old parts he had laying around in his house and we got it up in running. The first thing we did was install Ubuntu on it. Although Ubuntu is very fun to mess around with and more secure and useful than Windows, I wanted windows so I can play my games. So I went on my laptop and installed an ISO version of windows onto my USB flash drive with RUFUS and plugged it into my PC. I went through the boot sequence and I saw it did not detect any bootable drives. I believe this is how my friend installed Ubuntu before but I was not sure. So then I restarted my PC and tried going into the BIOS by pressing `delete` over and over again but it didn't work. I couldn't get into my BIOS anymore. How can i uninstall Ubuntu and get my PC running windows again?

Here are some random things that I couldn't fit in formally into the paragraph:

The last time I was in the BIOS it gave me a message telling me that my overclocking was causing problems.

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 (upgraded from 16.4).

My hard drive is brand new.

Comment: Different hardware uses different keys to get into BIOS/UEFI. You need the correct one for your PC (motherboard). Either pay attention when it's booting or consult your user's manual. It has nothing to do with the installed Ubuntu or any other OS, BIOS/UEFI "happens" before any OS is loaded. PS - You can have both in dual-boot.

Answer (score 3):

Your computer's UEFI or BIOS is stored on the motherboard, and is the first thing that the computer runs before it can even look for an operating system.  So nothing you do in regards to having (or not having) an operating system installed on your computer will affect that.  Every manufacturer triggers the UEFI/BIOS setting screen in a different way, though, so you'll need to check the manual for your motherboard for more information.  (Try searching the make and model number on Google.)

You don't really uninstall operating systems, you delete them.  If you are ever installing a new operating system and do not want the existing operating system and data on your computer, you just install the new operating system and tell the installer to use your entire disk.

Comment: Its possible that his friend somehow set an 'ultra fast boot' mode. Some high end motherboards have additional boot modes which skip input checking and deny bios access until it is cleared.

Comment: @Aedazan In that case all you have to do is press ESC immediately after powering on.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Or just change your bootloader's (most likely GRUB2) settings to have an option to boot from the USB drive…